# Composer won't install "require-dev" packages

Tags: composer-php

I'm trying to do some development with Laravel, and for some reason I can't get it to install any of the packages listed in the `require-dev` section in any of the dependencies' `composer.json` files.  AFAIK, dev dependencies are supposed to be installed by default.  I've tried it with and without the `--dev` flag on `composer install`.  I've also tried removing the contents of `vendors/` and deleting `composer.lock` and `~/.composer` and reinstalling all the dependencies from scratch, but still no luck.  I've also tried various iterations of the `composer update` command.

For example, in `vendor/laravel/framework/composer.json`, it lists these:

```
"require-dev": {
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.4.*",
    "iron-io/iron_mq": "1.4.*",
    "pda/pheanstalk": "2.1.*",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.8.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
},
```

None of these are getting installed.  Any ideas what am I missing?  Here's my main `composer.json` file, FWIW.

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
    "rncryptor/rncryptor-php": "1.*"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/libraries",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

I ran `composer self-update`, so it should be the latest version.  Running `composer --version` shows this:

```
Composer version b20021cc6aa113069e4223b78d0074a1fc7dd4e8 2014-01-14 16:22:09
```

Comment: Have you tried the `--require-dev` flag to force dev install?

Comment: I tried `composer install --require-dev` and `composer update --require-dev`, but both give me an error saying this flag doesn't exist.  I've tried with `--dev`, but no luck.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Composer only ever installs the packages listed as "require-dev" of your main composer.json file, and if these packages do need something else, then only their "require" packages are installed, but not their "require-dev" packages.

This actually is a good thing. If you want to contribute to an existing software package, you'd clone their repository, install everything needed for development, and are ready to contribute. But if you require that package for your own software, this is no use case to develop that particular package - it is the use case to develop your own software.

So the tl;dr: Composer only installs the development requirements of the composer.json, not of any dependencies.

Comment: I see.  I guess I just didn't understand what the documentation said when it meant "root".

Answer (score 5):

There is a solution for installing the require-dev packages of a vendor into your project.

https://github.com/wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin

Add this into your composer.json of your project

```
{
    "require": {
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "dev-master"
    },
    "extra": {
        "merge-plugin": {
            "include": [
                "vendor/laravel/framework/composer.json"
            ]
            "recurse": true,
            "replace": false,
            "ignore-duplicates": false,
            "merge-dev": true,
            "merge-extra": false,
            "merge-extra-deep": false,
            "merge-scripts": false
        }
    }
}
```

It is important to have `"merge-dev": true,`
run

```
composer update
```

And the require-dev packages of "vendor/laravel/framework/composer.json" will be installed in your project.