# Composer require-dev requireing dependencies in different packages require-dev

Tags: php, composer-php

I have some tests that are namespaced being autoloaded in package A using

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Vendor\\PackageA\\PhpUnit\\": "tests/PhpUnit"
    }
},
```

This works fine.

I have another package, package B which also have namespaced tests that require one of the namespaced tests in package A

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Vendor\\PackageB\\PhpUnit\\": "tests/PhpUnit"
    }
},
```

However, when I try and include the file in Package B, the class is not found

```
use Vendor\PackageA\PhpUnit\MyTestFromA;

class MyTestFromB extends MyTestFromA
{
```

Making me think that the autoload-dev stuff from other packages is not being loaded.

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Vendor\PackageA\PhpUnit\MyTestFromA' not found in /full/path/to/PackageBClass.php on line 3

When I try and import a file that is being autoloaded using `autoload` from package B rather than `autoload-dev`, I get no error.

How can I overcome this?

Part of me is thinking to make a package just for the tests and have it autoloaded in both without `autoload-dev` but I want to confirm first.

Comment: Duplicate + Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21171171/1163786

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution: [Composer autoload-dev does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36538972/composer-autoload-dev-does-not-work).

> Take a look at the [docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload-dev). It says: "autoload-dev **(root only)**". root only means it only applies to the root package. As you included the package, the shown `composer.json` file is not the root package and the `autoload-dev` section is thus ignored.